# Use a var to describe a var of a class

Tags: php, oop, scope

Basically I want to access a variable of a class, but I change the name of the wanted variable dynamically. I'm having a bit problems to explain exactly, but see my code, maybe it gets more clear:

```
$requirement = array('req1','req2');
foreach($requirements as $requirement)
        {
            // CHECK FOR REQUIRED PARAMETERS
            if(!isset($this->$requirement)) { echo 'foo'; }
        }
```

So I actually want to access `$this->req1` and so on, but how do I access it with my iterator-variable? I'm not sure whether this is right already, having difficulties to find out.

Also: How would I access a parents` variable in the same situation ?

Comment: Try `$this->{$requirement}`. And what is a parent in your case?

Comment: I mean a parent class that got extended. The stuff you access with `parent::$variable`

Comment: parent properties are available in the child object (unless defined as private in the parent, in which case you shouldn't be accessing them from the child)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ (or use magic getters/setters)

```
if(!isset($this->$$requirement)) { echo 'foo'; }
```

or

```
if(!isset($this->{$requirement})) { echo 'foo'; }
```

Comment: That should do! Is it `parent::${$requirement}` then for the parent ?

Comment: If you're extending a parent class, then all non-private properties should be available in that instance of the child class... so no need to access tem in any way differently

Answer (score 1):

I would use magic getters and setters, as Mark said. Like this:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    protected $data;

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->data[$key]
    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }
}

$var = 'adsdas';
$var2 = 'sadkajds';

$obj = new MyClass;
$obj->$var = 1;
$obj->$var2 = 1;
```

Comment: That's the way I'd usually go, but in my case it's a bit complicated to use, so I'll go with the brackets, thanks anyway!!